# Deduplicating value pairs between 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[This](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27029540#27029540) was asked in the SQL Helpline room:

> ```
> I have a sql query concern. Could you help me?
> It goes like this. I have a table with the Records
>
> A B
> A C
> B A
> B C
> C A
> C B
>
> How do I get only the records that there aren't duplicated in both columns
>
> A B
> A C
> B C
> ```

While it seemed simple at first, it was surprisingly difficult to get it to work. In the end, I had to resort to a loop. Please mind, this *looks* like example code, but it is more like practice code, so that the logic can be applied to real situations.

I saved a demo [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/428323) (which uses temp tables) and the query goes like this:

```
/* Assuming that @Origin is the source table your data currently is: */
declare @Origin table (val1 char(1), val2 char(1));
insert into @Origin (val1, val2) 
values
  ('A', 'B'),
  ('A', 'C'),
  ('B', 'A'),
  ('B', 'C'),
  ('C', 'A'),
  ('C', 'B');

/* Create a temp table in memory:
    Note: We could also use a physicial #holdingTable 
    if the result set is too large for memory */
declare @holdingTable table (
  rownum int primary key, 
  val1 char(1), 
  val2 char(1)
);
insert into @holdingTable (
    rownum, 
    val1, 
    val2
)
select 
  /* generate a rownum to use for looping: */
  row_number() over (order by val1, val2),
  /* add values from origin table: */
  val1,
  val2
from @Origin;

/* loop variables: */
declare @i int = (select min(rownum) from @holdingTable);
declare @max int = (select max(rownum) from @holdingTable);

/* deduplication variables: */
declare @val1Deduplicator char(1);
declare @val2Deduplicator char(1);

/* table to hold result set until end of query: */
declare @resultSet table (val1 char(1), val2 char(1));

while @i <= @max
begin
    /* assign values to deduplicate across columns: */
    select 
        /* inversion between val1 and val2 happens here: */
        @val1Deduplicator = val2, 
        @val2Deduplicator = val1
    from @holdingTable
    where rownum = @i;
    /* verify we are not inserting a duplicate: */
    if not exists (
        select 1 
        from @resultSet 
        where val1 = @val1Deduplicator
          and val2 = @val2Deduplicator
    )
    /* if confirmed not a duplicate, insert the values from the current row: */
    begin
        insert into @resultSet (val1, val2)
        select val1, val2 
        from @holdingTable
        where rownum = @i;
    end;
    /* increment loop: */
    set @i = @i + 1;
end;
/* obtain the final results: */
select * from @resultSet;
```

The performance seems OK for this few records, but it's not set-based and might get really slow for a large number of records. Is there a smarter way to do this? Is there anything else I can improve?

Output is correct:

> ```
> val1 val2 
> ---- ---- 
> A    B    
> A    C    
> B    C    
>
> (3 row(s) returned)
> ```

Comment: Thank you Phrancis. I was wondering if it was possible to do it with only query code. Forntantly, and bad for you because you lost some time with it, I no longer need it :p.

Comment: @BrunoCosta it was fun to learn :)

Comment: The comments in your source code indicate that you believe that table variables are memory only and #temp tables are "physical" - this is not the case. Both are held in pages in tempdb. The pages of both may reside entirely in memory, may be entirely on disc or any permutation in between, see the "Memory Only?"  heading here http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16386/3690

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `val1` and `val2` are comparable it is easy to find the distinct values, using set-based operations, by normalizing first and then taking distinct rows.

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable]
(
    [TestID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Value1] NCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    [Value2] NCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
)

INSERT INTO [TestTable]
    ([Value1], [Value2])
VALUES
    (N'A', N'B'),
    (N'A', N'C'),
    (N'B', N'A'),
    (N'B', N'C'),
    (N'C', N'A'),
    (N'C', N'B'),
    (N'D', N'C');
```

If you just need the values, and not the actual rows, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT` with a normalized CTE:

```
WITH [Normalized] AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [tt].[Value1] > [tt].[Value2] 
            THEN [tt].[Value2] 
            ELSE [tt].[Value1] END [N1],
        CASE WHEN [tt].[Value1] > [tt].[Value2] 
            THEN [tt].[Value1] 
            ELSE [tt].[Value2] END [N2]
    FROM
        [TestTable] [tt]
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    [n].[N1] [Value1],
    [n].[N2] [Value2]
FROM
    [Normalized] [n];
```

Result:

```
Value1 Value2
------ ------
A      B
A      C
B      C
C      D
```

If you need the original rows instead you have to eliminate the duplicates yourself. This can be done using the normalized CTE and partitioning by the normalized values:

```
WITH [Normalized] AS
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [tt].[Value1] > [tt].[Value2] 
            THEN [tt].[Value2] 
            ELSE [tt].[Value1] END [N1],
        CASE WHEN [tt].[Value1] > [tt].[Value2] 
            THEN [tt].[Value1] 
            ELSE [tt].[Value2] END [N2],
        [tt].[TestID],
        [tt].[Value1],
        [tt].[Value2]
    FROM
        [TestTable] [tt]
),
[Ranked] AS
(
    SELECT
        [n].[TestID],
        [n].[Value1],
        [n].[Value2],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [n].[N1], [n].[N2]
                           ORDER BY [n].[TestID] ASC) AS [Rank]
    FROM
        [Normalized] [n]
),
[Distinct] AS
(
    SELECT
        [r].[TestID],
        [r].[Value1],
        [r].[Value2]
    FROM
        [Ranked] [r]
    WHERE
        [r].[Rank] = 1
)
SELECT [d].[TestID], [d].[Value1], [d].[Value2]
FROM
    [Distinct] [d];
```

Result:

```
TestID      Value1 Value2
----------- ------ ------
1           A      B
2           A      C
4           B      C
7           D      C
```

As for performance, the iterative approach is, according to the execution plan in SSMS14, about 10 times slower. The set based solution is a table scan + a sort where as the execution plan for the iterative solution is a mess to look at.

Comment: That's very cool, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You just need the correct logic.

This returns one of pairs, prefering `A-B` over `B-A`:

```
SELECT val1,val2 -- need to add DISTINCT if there are duplicate rows
FROM @Origin t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT * FROM @Origin t2
  WHERE t1.val1 = t2.val2
    AND t1.val2 = t2.val1
    AND t1.val1 > t2.val1
);
```